# For loops being skipped without cause in VBA

Tags: algorithm, vba, excel, for-loop, excel-2010

My code, as written, works for all the ways I've tested it. I have two questions though.  First, Why in the blue blazes do I HAVE to use Do While loops instead of For loops in my code?  I've searched Everywhere I can to help me on this issue.  I can't reinstall excel, but I've reset as many of the settings as I can, but, invariably, the compiler skips over every for loop I have that isn't a for each loop... Except the first for loop in my programming... It is the weirdest and most bizarre behavior I have ever seen.  I have used step through (F8) 10000 times to try and figure out why it keeps skipping.  But every single time i make a for loop, it doesn't even run the first line of it.

To be clear, every place I have a Do While ... Loop, it *SHOULD* be a For Next. But making this change breaks the code every time because every spot the do while is changed to for, the code is skipped entirely. Even if I reset the i value to 0. The issue happens even if I have a different iterator for each loop.

Running w8 on an Intel i5 with Office 2010.

```
For i=1 To i = 100 
    If (i >= startRow And i <= stopRow And Not rowDone(i) And Not i = colFocus) Then
        colCurPayAmounts(i) = S_Debt.Cells(i, 5) 
    Else 
        colCurPayAmounts(i) = 0 
    End If i = i + 1 
Next i
```

Comment: Care to give an example of a `For...Next` loop that didn't run?

Comment: Tip - Remove all text not related to problem.  Your experience or lack of sleep is irrelevant to us being able to help you and wont help the next person who has the same problem and lands on your post.  An example of how your trying to use the `For` loop with out `Each` as @Rory mentioned is more important information.

Comment: Your story is too long to read thus, i dont think many people bother to read and try to help. You can start from deleting first paragraph

Comment: @Rory Yes, the kind of problem I'm seeing is: 
  `For i=1 To i = 100
            If (i >= startRow And i <= stopRow And Not rowDone(i) And Not i = colFocus) Then
                colCurPayAmounts(i) = S_Debt.Cells(i, 5)
            Else
                colCurPayAmounts(i) = 0
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next i`

Changing it from Do While i<=100 ... Loop breaks the entire code because colCurPayAmounts never changes to the new values.

Comment: The problem is it should be `For i = 1 To 100` and not `For i = 1 To i = 100`

Comment: Please remove your second question and ask it as a separate question on the site.

Comment: @Rory, I'm going to have to kick myself.  That was it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it should be For i = 1 To 100 and not For i = 1 To i = 100   @Rory

Comment: This was the issue.  I was not using the To operator correctly.