# For loop being skipped without any cause in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem:** After `For currentRow = 25 To rowCount`, the rest of the for statement keeps getting skipped for no cause.

I have two other For statements that comes before this problematic block of codes and their formats are the same as this and both work fine.

```
Public Sub WeightB()
    Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    sourceCol = 7
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For currentRow = 24 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
            Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have referred [For loops being skipped without cause in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356572/for-loops-being-skipped-without-cause-in-vba) and still haven't been able to figure this out.

Comment: What is the value of `rowCount` just before the `For` loop?

Comment: I tried MsgBox rowCount and it shows 22.

Comment: @Peh But then why the previous two statements worked? This is very strange to me. I really appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `rowCount`, as per your clarifying comment, is 22 then your `For` loop becomes

`For currentRow = 24 To 22`

which is obviously a no-op, as there is no way 24 can count up to 22. If you need to count in the *direction* of the final number then you could use something like

```
For currentRow = 24 To rowCount Step Iif(rowCount - 24 < 0, -1, +1)
```

but is this really what you want to do? Also, start using `Long` types for row and column numbers, now that worksheets have more than 32767 rows, and use `Option Explicit` at the top of all modules to obviate annoying spontaneous variable creation.

Comment: Worth mentioning, if this is intentional but you want to go from 24 to 22 (24,23,22) then the OP should use `For currentRow = 22 To 24 Step -1`

Comment: I might have answered you wrong. What I am trying to do is enter data from D24 to D42. But I want this script to find the empty cells in that range to enter the input.